# OutputLocation needs not to be specified in a lmbda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-athena

{
"errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter ResultConfiguration.OutputLocation, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'str'>",
"errorType": "ParamValidationError",
.......
}

what I want is to prevent mandatory storage of query

```
    ResultConfiguration={
        #'OutputLocation': 's3://' + params['bucket'] + '/' + params['path']
        'OutputLocation': None
    }
```

None instead of file path does not work

Comment: What do you want to do? A location is required, either in workgroup or your command.

Comment: I want to run athena SQL queries and the result needs not to be stored in S3

Comment: Hi pratyush! It would help people answer your question better if you could add more details explaining exactly what you're trying to achieve, what you have tried so far and why it isn't working. Code examples help a lot so sharing the code from your lambda function would likely help a lot here! It might help to review this article which explains how to ask a great question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: What type of query you are running and why do you don't want to store the result to S3?

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear why you require S3 location?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to run athena SQL queries and the result needs not to be stored in S3

You **can't do this**. If you have such a requirement, then you have to look at some custom solution or third party tool for querying your data in S3. Maybe EMR with Hive will be useful.